# PyTorch Lightningでの学習の実行でエラーがでます

Tags: python, pytorch

PyTorch Lightningをつかってネットワークの学習をしようとししているのですが、

```
# 学習の実行
trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
```

を実行しようとしたところ、下記エラーがでます。
何が原因なのでしょうか？

コードファイルの添付いいたします

```
INFO:pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_summary:
  | Name | Type   | Params
--------------------------------
0 | fc1  | Linear | 20    
1 | fc2  | Linear | 15    
--------------------------------
35        Trainable params
0         Non-trainable params
35        Total params
0.000     Total estimated model params size (MB)
Sanity Checking:
0/? [00:00<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-559331086c50> in <module>
      1 # 学習の実行
----> 2 trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in fit(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    601             raise TypeError(f"`Trainer.fit()` requires a `LightningModule`, got: {model.__class__.__qualname__}")
    602         self.strategy._lightning_module = model
--> 603         call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
    604             self, self._fit_impl, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path
    605         )

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py in _call_and_handle_interrupt(trainer, trainer_fn, *args, **kwargs)
     36             return trainer.strategy.launcher.launch(trainer_fn, *args, trainer=trainer, **kwargs)
     37         else:
---> 38             return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
     39 
     40     except _TunerExitException:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _fit_impl(self, model, train_dataloaders, val_dataloaders, datamodule, ckpt_path)
    643             model_connected=self.lightning_module is not None,
    644         )
--> 645         self._run(model, ckpt_path=self.ckpt_path)
    646 
    647         assert self.state.stopped

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run(self, model, ckpt_path)
   1096         self._checkpoint_connector.resume_end()
   1097 
-> 1098         results = self._run_stage()
   1099 
   1100         log.detail(f"{self.__class__.__name__}: trainer tearing down")

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_stage(self)
   1175         if self.predicting:
   1176             return self._run_predict()
-> 1177         self._run_train()
   1178 
   1179     def _pre_training_routine(self) -> None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_train(self)
   1188 
   1189         with isolate_rng():
-> 1190             self._run_sanity_check()
   1191 
   1192         # enable train mode

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _run_sanity_check(self)
   1260             # run eval step
   1261             with torch.no_grad():
-> 1262                 val_loop.run()
   1263 
   1264             self._call_callback_hooks("on_sanity_check_end")

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    197             try:
    198                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 199                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    200                 self.on_advance_end()
    201                 self._restarting = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/dataloader/evaluation_loop.py in advance(self, *args, **kwargs)
    150         if self.num_dataloaders > 1:
    151             kwargs["dataloader_idx"] = dataloader_idx
--> 152         dl_outputs = self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher, dl_max_batches, kwargs)
    153 
    154         # store batch level output per dataloader

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/loop.py in run(self, *args, **kwargs)
    197             try:
    198                 self.on_advance_start(*args, **kwargs)
--> 199                 self.advance(*args, **kwargs)
    200                 self.on_advance_end()
    201                 self._restarting = False

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py in advance(self, data_fetcher, dl_max_batches, kwargs)
    135 
    136         # lightning module methods
--> 137         output = self._evaluation_step(**kwargs)
    138         output = self._evaluation_step_end(output)
    139 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/epoch/evaluation_epoch_loop.py in _evaluation_step(self, **kwargs)
    232         """
    233         hook_name = "test_step" if self.trainer.testing else "validation_step"
--> 234         output = self.trainer._call_strategy_hook(hook_name, *kwargs.values())
    235 
    236         return output

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py in _call_strategy_hook(self, hook_name, *args, **kwargs)
   1478 
   1479         with self.profiler.profile(f"[Strategy]{self.strategy.__class__.__name__}.{hook_name}"):
-> 1480             output = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   1481 
   1482         # restore current_fx when nested context

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pytorch_lightning/strategies/strategy.py in validation_step(self, *args, **kwargs)
    388         with self.precision_plugin.val_step_context():
    389             assert isinstance(self.model, ValidationStep)
--> 390             return self.model.validation_step(*args, **kwargs)
    391 
    392     def test_step(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Optional[STEP_OUTPUT]:

<ipython-input-13-80fd211086af> in validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx)
     28         loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
     29         self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
---> 30         self.log('val_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t), on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
     31         return loss
     32 

TypeError: accuracy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'
```

Comment: 「PyTorch Lightningをつかってネットワークの学習をしようとししている」モデル部分のコードを追記いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼いたしました。コード添付いたします。https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19sMf_sMxy2Kb5uNjrB84Z9lsAIAtxs7M?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

エラー出力の最後に

```
TypeError: accuracy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'task'
```

とあるので，[TorchMetrics--ACCURACY--Functional Interface](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/accuracy.html#functional-interface) を参考に `task='multiclass', num_classes=3` を3カ所の `accuracy()` に設定して実行したところエラーは発生しなくなりました。なお，Google Colab (Python 3.8.16, torch 1.13.0+cu116, pytorch-lightning 1.8.6, torchmetrics 0.11.0) での確認に用いた（提示されたノートブックから集めた）コードは下記になります。

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from pytorch_lightning.loggers import CSVLogger
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy


class Net(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 4)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(4, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self.fc1(x)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.fc2(h)
        return h

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('train_loss', loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        self.log('train_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t,
                                       task='multiclass', num_classes=3),
                 on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('val_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('val_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t,
                                     task='multiclass', num_classes=3),
                 on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x, t = batch
        y = self(x)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(y, t)
        self.log('test_loss', loss, on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        self.log('test_acc', accuracy(y.softmax(dim=-1), t,
                                      task='multiclass', num_classes=3),
                 on_step=False, on_epoch=True)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)
        return optimizer


torch.manual_seed(0)
pl.seed_everything(0)

iris = load_iris()
data = iris['data']
target = iris['target']
data = torch.tensor(data, dtype=torch.float32)
target = torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.int64)
dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(data, target)

n_train = int(len(dataset) * 0.6)
n_val = int(len(dataset) * 0.2)
n_test = len(dataset) - n_train - n_val
train, val, test = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [n_train, n_val, n_test])

batch_size = 10
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size,
                                           shuffle=True, drop_last=True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test, batch_size)

net = Net()

logger = CSVLogger(save_dir='logs', name='my_exp')
trainer = pl.Trainer(max_epochs=30, deterministic=True, logger=logger)

trainer.fit(net, train_loader, val_loader)
```